# What's the integer read from a exe file

Tags: c++, operating-system

As we know, a ordinary application on windows start by PE header, and the first two character is "MZ".
So I have a C++ program to open a exe file and read it.
As I predicted, the character displayed is "MZ".But the integer be read is unintelligible and different every time.
So what the integer has been read is?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream ifs;
    ifs.open("a.exe", ios::in);
    char c[2];
    ifs >> c[0] >> c[1];
    cout << c[0] << c[1] << endl;
    ifs.close();
    ifs.open("a.exe", ios::in);
    int i;
    ifs >> i;
    cout << i << endl;
    ifs.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I was used a HTML code to show C++ code, but it's seems not good to read.It's a simple C++ code to open a exe file and read a integer using ifstream by operator >>, the integer is unintelligible and different every time

Comment: I suspect that the next two bytes after the 'MZ' magic number are 'don't care' for PE files and are only filler for a legacy MS-DOS header struct.  If don't care, they were probably never initialized to anything meaningful by the compiler/linker that generated the exe.

Answer (score 1):

The attempt to parse the file as an integer fails because the file begins with a character that is not legal in an integer. This leaves whatever junk was in `i` before still there. Essentially, you're just printing the value of a variable whose value has never been set.

Try changing:

```
int i;
```

to:

```
int i = 42;
```

And watch what happens.